# eclipse override method error on java 6, compiler 1.6

Tags: java, eclipse, methods, overriding, java-6

Eclipse is giving an error whenever I try to Override a superclass method. Even simple codes are giving errors. This is the class First

```
public class First{
private void Meth(){
}  
}
```

This is another class extending first

```
public class Second extends First{
@Override
public void meth(){
}
}
```

And eclipse gives error "The method meth() of type Second must override or implement a supertype method" "1 quick fix available - Remove '@Override' annotation ". I have already set the Compiler Compliance level to 1.6. Help!!

Answer (score 7, accepted):

1) You can't `Override` `private` methods.

2) As soon as eclipse/compiler see `@Override` statement, it tries to look for relevant `protected (or) public` method in super class, which is not there. That is why compiler error.

Comment: Anyway, `meth` is different from `Meth`.